# python simple parallel computation with joblib

Tags: python, joblib

I took example from [joblib tutorial](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html). Here is how my code looks like:

```
from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

test = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(10))
print(test)
```

It produces the following error message:

```
Attempting to do parallel computing without protecting your import
on a system that does not support forking. To use parallel-computing 
in a script, you must protect you main loop using 
"if __name__ == '__main__'". Please see the joblib documentation on 
Parallel for more information
```

And it runs for too long. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you read the documentation that the error message is telling you to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the error message and BrenBran are telling you is that a) you should read the error message, and b) you should organise your code something like:

```
from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(10))
    print(test)
```

HTH
barny

Answer (score 0):

I had to add backend="threading" to barny's code to run without error:

```
from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Parallel(n_jobs=2, backend="threading")(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(10))
print(test)
```

Comment: I was reviewing the docs and if we use     backend="threading" then it may lead to Global interpreter lock of python.